# I have read the statement Expectation of two independent variable X and Y E(XY)=0. How to prove it?

Tags: statistics, means, standard-deviation, cross-product

I know that if X and Y are independent variables then the expectation value of X and Y i.e $ E(XY)=E(X).E(Y).$ But then the expectation value will be equal to zero only when either of them i.e $E(X) or E(Y) $ is zero. Also, I have read somewhere that each term averages out to zero. But this can happen only for certain datasets/distributions right? How to generalize this?

This concept is frequently used while deriving standard deviation of sampling standard deviations, also in statistical mechanics where we drop cross terms averages.

[image: Derivation of variance of sample variance distribution]

Comment: $E[X_i]=\mu$ so $E[X_i-\mu]=0$ and $E[(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)]=0$ when $i\not= j$ as the two multiplicands are independent and have $0$ expectation.  But $E[(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)]=E[(X_i-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$ when $i=j$ as they are not independent